# Deploy failing due to insufficient access exception

Tags: managed-package, permission-sets, insufficient-privileges

I'm trying to deploy my managed package to a freshly installed org for a system admin user. I'm running into insufficient access errors for my custom objects. The problem as I see it is, that the the OWD settings for the custom object is set to private which are somehow causing these errors.
When I assign a permissionset to the test user, giving access to the custom objects , the test succeeds.

However, I do not understand why the test would fail under system context for a sys admin user. The system admin user by default should have access to all objects and I shouldnt have to assign the permission set to them. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Just because you're an admin user doesn't mean you have access to everything.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm kind of basing my assumption based on the response to this query - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164800/permission-model-on-managed-package.      "Should I be providing permission to the System admin for all fields/objects? Or the System admin can assign the permission set to itself after install?
System Administrator has Modify All Data, and the system also automatically gives them permission to all components on install. There's generally no need for a System Administrator to assign permissions to themselves."

Comment: Do private OWD settings do not have the same behavior for an administrator?

Comment: Modify All Data doesn't override FLS on object fields or objects without R(ead) permission. OWD is about record sharing, not object/field visibility